# Detect iPhone browser in .htaccess/apache and redirect to iPhone site

Tags: iphone, apache, .htaccess, user-agent

Is it possible to detect iPhone browser agent in .htaccess and redirect the user to the correct iPhone page?

Comment: Yes. (I don't know exactly how, but that wasn't your question ;) )

Comment: do it in PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] is the browser string . ANd then redirect using Location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can -

```
   #redirect mobile browsers
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPhone.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlackBerry.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Palm.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com [R=301]
```

Taken from [here](http://dev-tips.com/featured/redirect-iphone-blackberry-palm-requests-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

A little Googling, even has a handy generator. http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Tommy's response, if you want to pass through the URI, change the RewriteRules to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.yourdomain.com$1 [R=301]
```

Otherwise you'll be redirecting all requests to the mobile home page (though that might be what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified [RewiteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) that combines the mobile user agents into a single condition:

```
# Redirect Mobile Devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You'll notice that the [NC] [nocase flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc) is set, which causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a *case-insensitive* manner.

That is, it doesn't care whether the user agents strings appear as upper-case, camel-case or lower-case in the matched URI. (e.g., IPHONE vs. iPhone vs. iphone).